# Odd behaviour from compiler optimizing this loop

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, arm

I wrote this code to find the highest temperature pixel in a thermal image. I also need to know the coordinates of the pixel in the image.

```
void _findMax(uint16_t* image, int sz, sPixelData* returnPixel)
{
    int temp = 0;
    uint16_t max = image[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < sz; i++)
    {
        if(max < image[i])
        {
            max=image[i];
            //temp = i;
        }
    }

    returnPixel->temperature = image[temp];

    //returnPixel->x_location = temp % IMAGE_HORIZONTAL_SIZE;
    //returnPixel->y_location = temp / IMAGE_HORIZONTAL_SIZE;
}
```

With the three lines commented out the function executes in about 2ms. With the lines uncommented it takes about 35ms to execute the function.

This seems very excessive seeing as the divide and modulus are only performed once after the loop.

Any suggestions on how to speed this up?

Or why it takes so long to execute compared to the divide on modulus not include?

This is executing on an ARM A9 processor running Linux.

The compiler I'm using is ARM v8 32-Bit Linux gcc compiler.

I'm using optimize -O3 and the following compile options:  -march=armv7-a+neon -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon-fp16 -ftree-vectorize.

Comment: If you don't update `temp`, it's always 0 and the function only executes `returnPixel->temperature = image[0]`. The compiler correctly identifies that the loop is not needed and removes it.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, my question is, why does the function take so much longer to execute when in theory, just one extra divide and modulus after the loop has executed. The loop only has the extra `temp = i;`, so that should only cause it to take about twice as long surely?

Comment: No, these are two completely different programs: one with a loop (see https://godbolt.org/z/555qsM) and the other one consisting of three assembler instructions only (see https://godbolt.org/z/bGcYb1)

Comment: Why don't you use neon?

Comment: Not an answer, using the `register` modifier will shorten runtime if that is your real concern.

Comment: How would I write the code so that the compiler uses the neon instructions?

Comment: Is `IMAGE_HORIZONTAL_SIZE` an integer constant? If so, the compiler ought to optimize the division into a reciprocal multiplication and shift. Check the output from the assembler.

Comment: It seems that you are looking for a way to optimize your code. The current question won't be helpful. As one of the variants is flawed, you are comparing two things that basically have nothing to do with each other. So you are probably better off asking a new question with the real question: how to make the code faster.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is flawed.
Since `temp` is simply 0, the complier will generate machine codes that just executes `returnPixel->temperature = image[0];` which gets finished in no time. There is nothing odd here.

You should modify the line to: `returnPixel->temperature = max;`

You could boost the performance significantly by utilizing neon. But that's another problem.

Comment: Thanks I missed that, this is code after taking suggestions from other engineers at work, and I didn't notice that. The original code had  returnPixel->temperature being set directly. Thanks.